# Olympiad-type combinatorial problem on convex polyhedra

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Consider a convex polyhedron $P$ in three-dimensional Euclidean space. Let $V$ be the set of vertices and $E$ be the set of edges of $P$.

I use the following ad-hoc definition of a **mapping**: A **mapping on P** is any function from $E$ to the set $\{-1, +1\}$.

An additional ad-hoc definition: given a polyhedron $P$ as above, with vertices $V$ and edges $E$, and a mapping $m$ (as just defined), for every vertex $v \in V$ let the **product at $v$** be the product of the $-1$ and $+1$ values associated by $m$ to the edges that have $v$ as one of the endpoints.

With these definitions, prove the following:

1. For every polyhedron $P$ with 2019 vertices, and for every mapping on $P$, there is always at least one vertex $v$ so that the product at $v$ is $+1$.
2. For ***every*** polyhedron $P$ with 2020 vertices, there is at least one mapping on $P$ so that the product at $v$ is $-1$ for ***all*** vertices $v \in V$.

Of these, 1. is relatively easy (and relatively standard for an olympiad problem). The interesting problem, really, is 2.

Make sure you understand 2. correctly. It is not about finding one counterexample to 1. on some polyhedron with 2020 vertices; that's very easy. Rather, it is to show that 1. fails for **all** polyhedra with 2020 vertices, no matter what their (combinatorial) shape.

**BACKGROUND**: A very long time ago I created this problem and we used it in one of the examinations to select our national team for the IMO. There was no Internet then (at least, certainly, not in the East European country I'm from), so I doubt it very strongly that this problem has ever made it to the Internet. Obviously, I have a solution (my own!) but I am offering this as a fun challenge to math enthusiasts on SE. It will be fun to see what other solutions are being offered.

Comment: The first problem appears in Engel's Problem-Solving Strategies as problem 36 of the Games chapter (which is odd since it has nothing to do with a game). But as you said, it is a standard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

$$\prod_{v \in V} \text{product at } v = \prod_{v} \prod_{v \in e } P(e) = \prod_{e} P(e)^2 = 1.$$
Hence the number of vertices that have product of -1 is even, so an odd number (in particular, at least 1) of vertices have a product of 1.

2.

**Claim:** For any connected graph with an even number $n=2m$ of vertices, we can find a subset of edges such that the degree at each vertex is odd.

**Proof:** This is an olympiad problem, of which there are several (pretty distinct) solutions.
The solution that I like takes the symmetric difference of $m$ paths, connecting distinct vertices. Adding a path changes the parity of the endpoints and nothing else, thus the resultant parity of each vertices degree is odd.

**Corollary:** Giving those edges $-1$ will lead to each vertex having a product of $-1$.

---

Note:

1. We don't need "convex polytope" graph. No special features of it were used, other than connectedness in part 2. Specifically,

- Any graph with an odd number of vertices will have an odd number of vertices with a product of 1.
- Any connected graph with an even number of vertices will yield a mapping such that all vertices have a product of -1.

2. The olympiad problem I referenced is essentially identical to yours, just with a different skin. I don't know which was published first.

Comment: Perfect. My proof for part 2., which is essentially the same argument as you described (if I understand it correctly - I believe I do), went like this: divide the vertices into two disjoint sets of 1010 vertices each. Pair each vertex from the first subset with a vertex from the second. Join each such pair by a path. Initially assign +1 to all edges, and then go over the path, one at a time, in each step changing the sign of every edge in the path. The product at every vertex changes exactly once in the whole process; we started with +1 at every vertex, so we end up with -1 at every vertex.

Comment: Indeed, we only use connectedness and even cardinality in part 2. In our IMO preparations, as is true of the IMO itself, we didn't assume knowledge of math above the standard 10-th grade curriculum, so polyhedra, vertices etc. were OK, but graphs, connected graphs etc. weren't in the vocabulary. As I proposed the problem, I worried about some students spending time proving that polyhedral graphs are connected (which is not trivial with elementary means), but happily the real-life experience showed that they all took it as "granted".

Comment: Mildly curious about the "olympiad problem". Do you remember in what country, and the approximate time? It was almost surely an independent discovery (it's not that unusual of a fact, really). I proposed this problem in Romania, I don't remember exactly if it was 1980 or 1981. If it was ever "published" it was certainly only in hard copy, not online, and only in Romanian. It is more likely, in my opinion, that if you saw this in an olympiad in, say, Korea, it was found independently. Less likely: one of the Romanian students from 1980, now in Italy, say, would have used it there in 2010... :-)

Comment: @mathguy A) Yes, that's my proof for part 2. There are other solutions that involve the spanning tree, or via induction. B) Oh interesting that you stuck to curricular syllabus. C) I can find references of BAMO 2005/4 and Tournament of the Towns Spring 2011 Senior, which are in the skin that I remember. Though, I'm almost certain I saw it before 2002 when I was training for the IMO.

Comment: Yes, I like this one!