# Exists a non-empty subset $K$ of $2005$ senators in senat such that for every senator, the number of his enemies in $K$ is an even number.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory, contest-math

> There are $2005$ senators in a senate. Each senator has enemies within the senate. Prove that there exists a non-empty subset $K$ of senators such that for every senator in the senate, the number of his enemies in $K$ is an even number.

Let $n=2005$ and let $s_i$ be an indicator vector for $i$-th senator. So we are working in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ and we are looking for such a vector $u$ that $s_i\cdot u =0$ for all $i$.

Now we can make a matrix $M = [s_1,...,s_n]$ which is symmetric and thus it has $\det M =0$ since $n$ is odd. So it has nontrivial kernel so there exists $u\ne 0$ such that $Mu=0$. Clearly $u$ is a vector we are looking for and thus we are done.

---

Now, I wonder if it can be done **without** matrix theory, only in terms of linear independence and ''similar things''from linear algebra. My idea was to put $S := \langle s_1,s_2,...,s_n \rangle$ and prove that $S^{\bot} $ is nontrivial, which would be true if $s_1,s_2,...,s_n$ are lineary dependent.

All I can think is that by handshake lemma and since $n$ is odd, at least one senator has even number of enemies. Suppose it is $s_1$, so if $s_1\cdot s_j =0$ for all $j>1$ we are done. But what if that is not the case.

Comment: Are we to assume that enemies is a symmetric relation (i.e., if $x$ is an enemy of $y$, is $y$ necessarily an enemy of $x$?

Comment: Yeah, that would be reasonable. @paw88789

Comment: Would the first answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789438/determinant-of-a-special-symmetric-matrix) be too much matrix theory?  On a separate note, you might enjoy [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3926381/olympiad-type-combinatorial-problem-on-convex-polyhedra/3927353#3927353).

Comment: I think it is possible to cook up an algorithm that produces the set $K$ as follows. We can replace senators with "virtual senators" (= XORs of existing sets of senators) recursively in such a way that after each step no virtual senator is its own enemy (this would be absurd), and then in an iteration we find a pair of virtual senators who are each others enemies but friends with every other (virtual) senator. We can then continue with the remaining (virtual) senators, find the next pair. In the end (for reasons of parity) we end up with an odd number of virtual senators no one hates.

Comment: My idea is basically to apply transformations $M\mapsto M'=PMP^T$ where $M'$ has zero diagonal, and $P$ is effectively either a 2x2 or a 3x3 lower triangular invertible matrix (according to what is required to simplify a fixed column). Basically running an algorithm that puts a symmetric bilinear form over $\Bbb{F}_2^n$ into a standard form. Not satisfactory, but...

Comment: So $M$ symmetric in $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb F_2)$ with an odd $n$ has always determinant zero? (The OP is very expeditive in this important line.) It would be nice to mention that $M$ has zero entries on the diagonal, (else the unit matrix is a counterexample,) to be as detailed in this line as in the lines given restrictions to the shape and ingredients of the wanted solutions. The own laconic attempt to solve the issue is mentioning the handshake lemma, well, an ingredient also outside linear algebra - so maybe solutions hitting the wound point by using graph theory should be accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility to "not use matrices, but linear algebra". (Bilinear forms, and use "symplectic" ideas.)

Let $n$ be an odd positive integer. Let $F$ be the field with two elements and $V=F^n$ the canonical vector space of dimension $n$ over $F$. (Elements are identified with column vectors with $n$ components in $F$.)

Let $e_1, e_2,\dots,e_n$ be the canonical basis of $V$.
Let $e_I$ be $\displaystyle e_I=\sum_{i\in I}e_i$ for some subset $I$ of the index set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. Each element of $V$ is of the shape $e_I$ for a suitable $I$.

Let $B$ be the symmetric bilinear form so that
$B(e_i,e_j)$ is the $j$'th component in $s_i$ and/or the $i$'th component in $s_j$.

(*Comment:* The associated matrix $S$ for this bilinear form is the matrix with columns $s_1,\dots,s_n$, and $B(v,w)=v'Sw$. Note that it is essential that no senator feels to be its own enemy, translated by the fact that the diagonal entries in $S$ are all zero. The OP should have mentioned this in the row that claims $\det S=0$. This comment is not part of the solution, we will tacitly use $B(e_i, e_i)=0$, equivalent to $S_{ii}$=0, a relation which is valid for all $i$.)

Assume that this bilinear form is non-degenerated.
(We try to develop a contradiction.)

This form is not only skew-symmetric (since it is symmetric, and we are in characteristic two), but also alternating:
$$
B(e_I,e_I)
=\sum_{i,j\in I}B(e_i, e_j)
=\sum_{i\in I}B(e_i, e_i) 
+2
\sum_{\substack{i,j\in I\\i<j}}B(e_i, e_j)
=0\ .
$$
An alternating $B$ can live only in *even dimension*. Contradiction.

So $B$ has non-trivial kernel.
(From the degeneration, we obtain a non-zero $v\in V$ in the kernel of the canonical map $V\to V^*$ induced by $B$, so $w\to B(w,v)=w'Sv$ is the zero map in $V^*$, so $Sv$ is the zero vector.)

$\square$

---

Here is the argument involved (induction with step two on $n=\dim V$) for the *even dimension* above. ("Not using matrices", it is the usual argument, mentioned explicitly to show that the idea can be accepted in the thematic of the OP, passing to the orthogonal space is used for instance.)

Let $B$ be alternating, non-degenerated on $V$. If $\dim V=0$ there is nothing to show. If $\dim V=1$ then it has only one non-zero vector $v\in V\cong\Bbb F_2$, and from $B(v,v)=0$ we obtain $B=0$, contradiction. So the needed property holds for all vector spaces with dimension $<2$. Let $V$ be a space of dimension $\ge 2$ now. There is some $u\in V$, $u\ne 0$. Since $B(u,u)=0$, but $B(u,\cdot)\not \equiv 0$, there is some $v\in V$ with $B(u,v)=1$.
Consider now the subspace $U=\langle u,v\rangle$, and its orthogonal complement w.r.t. $B$,
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
W=U^\perp\ .
$$
Then standard arguments show that $V=U\oplus W$, and consider for the inductive step the restiction of $B$ to $W$, again alternating and non-degenerated.

(Explicitly, and without matrices: Since $B$ is non-degenerated, $U\cap W=U\cap U^\perp=0$, since none of the only non-zero elements of $U$, enumerated as $u$, $v$, $u+v$, lies in $U^\perp$. We further need the property $U+U^\perp=V$. Consider for this the map into the dual $U\to U^*$, $y\to B(y,\cdot)\Big|_U$, given explicitly by
$0\to 0$, $u\to B(u,\cdot)\Big|_U$, $v\to B(v,\cdot)\Big|_U$, $u+v\to B(u+v,\cdot)\Big|_U$. It is injective, thus surjective, so an isomorphism of linear spaces of dimension two.

Then for each $x\in V$ the form $B(x,\cdot)\Big|_U$ can be realized with an element $y\in U$. So $B(x-y,y')=0$ for all $y'\in U$. This means $x-y\in U^\perp = W$, realizing $x\in y+W\subset U+W$.)

---

*Note:* A matrix $M$ as the given one is exactly a matrix for an alternating bilinear form.